# Submit form from jQuery modal to a ColdFusion action page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to submit a really simple form in my ColdFusion application to an action page to have some database records updated.

When I submit the form, Firebug is telling me

> 500 (Element NOTETEXT is undefined in FORM.)

Here is my JavaScript

```
 <!---Javascript that submits the link notes changes --->                                               
        <script>
           $(function(){
            $("#noteForm").submit(function(){
               // prevent native form submission here
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $('#noteForm').serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: "actionpages/link_notes_action.cfm?id=2",
                        success: function(responseSubmit) {
                        alert("Success");
                        }

                    });
                    return false;           
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Here is my form

```
 <form id="noteForm">

   <textarea id="noteText" name="noteText" cols="45" rows="10">#notes#</textarea><br />
   <input name="submit" id="submitForm" type="submit" value="Update">
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="#get_dashboard_links.ID#">

</form>
```

And here is my action page:

```
<cfquery name="update"   datasource="#datasource#">
  update dashboard_links
  set notes = '#form.noteText#'
  where ID = #form.hidden#
</cfquery>
```

[image]

Comment: Might be the cause of the issue, but remove `cfform` and `cfinput`. In this example, you gain nothing from using them, and they might be getting in the way. Use `<form>` and `<input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Developer Tools (in Chrome) or FireBug (in Firefox) when you are submitting the form, I bet you are not actually passing any data to your 'action page'. While you are calling `serialize()` on the form, you are not actually passing it to the page.

Try adding the following to your `$.ajax()` call:

```
data: JSON.stringify( data ),
```

Also, if you are returning JSON, use this

```
dataType: 'json',
```

This will tell jQuery to automatically handle the results as JSON.

Comment: Thanks. I added those two lines into my script. It still is not working but it is now refreshing the page when I hit my submit button whereas before the MODAL would stay in the forefront and I could see the error message in firebug. Now, I see an error message flash through the console, but once the page reloads it goes away. I have also tried inserting "preventDefault();" but that does not stop the page refresh.

Comment: Neither of those should have affected the way the ajax request is processed. Try just the first one. Also, make sure if you added them to the end and the last character in the block is the trailing comma, remove the comma.

Comment: I actually adjusted the script slightly to add the prevent.default clause in a different way as well as included your edits. I'll update my post with new the code. I now receive: data is not defined.

Comment: I also updated my form code as per you suggestion. I will up date the post accordingly.

Comment: You can look in Firbug to see what form fields are being sent to ColdFusion. Lets make sure the browser is sending them before we check  if ColdFusion is getting them. 2 different problems that require different angles of attack.

Comment: In firebug, I can drill down under the DOM tab and I can see a field called value under the textarea element and it has my value of "test" that I am typing in there. Is that how I would validate the data being there? I added a screenshot to my post of what I am seeing there.

Comment: Not the DOM tab, the Network tab. It shows data being sent back and forth (you will likely see all the related files in there as well)

Comment: I don't see anything in the Network tab relating to my form data or the content of my MODAL.

Comment: Using firefox, I inspected the element and confirmed that the Network tab also doesn't show anything. When I click my submit button, no information passes through that tab.

Comment: Ok, I think I am getting somewhere now. I updated this post with the new JavaScript code I am using. With this iteration, I can see my data being sent over to my action page in the "Network Tab" in firebug. No errors are thrown in the console but I'm assuming that my query is not executing properly because my record never updates with the data that is passed. Ugh!

Comment: Nevermind it is now working!! My hidden variable was pulling from a different query. Once I specified the query in my variable, it worked. I'll update my post with the edit. Thanks for all your insight!

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion keys off of the name of the form object, not the ID.

Change your textarea to

```
<cftextarea id="noteText" name="noteText" cols="45" rows="10">
```

*OR*

Change your action page thusly:

```
set notes = '#form.notes#'
```

(By the way, I hope you're not actually updating your database with that unfiltered input. You are using `cfqueryparam`, right?)

Comment: I modified the CFtextarea to match your code, still same result: 500 (Element NOTETEXT is undefined in FORM.) I was planing on replacing the where cluse in my CFQUERY code once I got this working.

Comment: dump the form on your page and see what's being passed. If you've really copied his code it should show in the form scope.

Comment: I've added <cfdump var="#form#"> to my action page, but how am I able to see the dump if it is doing a ajax post?

Comment: use firebug or another set of dev tools

Comment: I often will wrap `<cfdump>` inside a `<cfsavecontent>` then write the whole thing to an HTML file in the same directory as the template.